# partially persistent data structure for python

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm working in Python, and need an implementation of a  [partially persistent data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Partially_persistent) .

For this data structure I need the following functionality:

- dictionary (key-value , insert,update,delete,search)
- insert,update,delete -  each action is given a timestamp as additional input (new timestamp must be bigger than older ones used on the data structure).
- can search data structure history given a timestamp.

Tarjan's persistent search tree (widely used in computational geometry) answers perfectly to this but I can't find an implementation for it in Python, only in C.

does anyone know about such an existing implementation for this kind of data structure in Python?

Comment: Why dont you try to reimplement the C version you have into python.. I am sure its not that difficult.

Comment: This [link][1] is similar to what you want.. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432760/explaining-persistent-data-structures-in-simple-terms

Comment: You could be able to use the C library through `ctypes`...